# How to access an environement locally defined in a package from Rcpp?

Tags: r, package, environment, rcpp

I have a package which defines a local environment *options*. Functions in that same package written in R, can access this environment **without** the need to export it:

```
options <- new.env()
options$foo <- "bar"

foobar <- function() {
    flag = options$foo == "bar"
    flag
}
```

when I try to do the same thing from Rcpp:

```
bool foobar() {
    bool flag = false;
    Environment env("package:myPackage");
    SEXP o = env.get("options");
    Environment options(o);
    if (options.exists("foo")) {
        std::string bar = as<std::string>(options["foo"]);
        flag = (bar == "bar");
    }
    return flag;
}
```

this **only** works if I add *export(options)* to NAMESPACE. So I solved the problem myself, but am curious to know if this apparent asymmetry w.r.t. the export requirement is expected or if my implementation of the Rcpp function is to blame?

Comment: The attached package environment only contains exported symbols, so attempting to find `options` in the default way won't resolve it. You'll need to get `options` out of the package's namespace, rather than looking for the environment attached by your package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to extract the symbol from the package's namespace, rather than the attached package environment.

For example, compare these two methods for resolving `utils:::argNames`, which is an unexported function within the `utils` namespace:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP ns_symbol(const std::string& pkg, const std::string& symbol) {
   Environment env = Environment::namespace_env(pkg);
   return env[symbol];
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP pkg_symbol(const std::string& pkg, const std::string& symbol) {
   Environment env("package:" + pkg);
   return env[symbol];
}


/*** R
library(utils)
ns_symbol("utils", "argNames")
pkg_symbol("utils", "argNames")
*/
```

Running this with `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` gives me:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('lookup.cpp')

> library(utils)

> ns_symbol("utils", "argNames")
function (fname, use.arg.db = .CompletionEnv$settings[["argdb"]]) 
{
    if (use.arg.db) 
        args <- .FunArgEnv[[fname]]
    if (!is.null(args)) 
        return(args)
    args <- do.call(argsAnywhere, list(fname))
    if (is.null(args)) 
        character()
    else if (is.list(args)) 
        unlist(lapply(args, function(f) names(formals(f))))
    else names(formals(args))
}
<bytecode: 0x7ff40889e6d0>
<environment: namespace:utils>

> pkg_symbol("utils", "argNames")
NULL
```

As you can see, the symbol was resolved within the package's namespace, but not within the attached environment.